# How can JDBC URLs be parsed for extracting connection properties in mysql-connector-java 8.0?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0

My application uses `mysql-connector-java-5.1.48` and I'm trying to migrate to `mysql-connector-java-8.0.15`. The application currently uses [NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/ad86f36e100e104cd926c6b81c8cab9565750116/src/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java#L588) to parse the jdbc url and return the Properties extracted from the URL as follows:

```
  NonRegisteringDriver driver = new NonRegisteringDriver();
  Properties properties = driver.parseURL(connectUrl, null);
```

How can I do something similar using the 8.0.x connector version since it no longer has the parseURL API?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454) to me. Why are you even parsing the URL in the first place? Only the JDBC driver itself should care what those values are.

Comment: It is for security purposes. I would like to allow only the approved set of properties configured in the application. So I use the properties to compare against the allow list and fail the connection if non-allowed properties are used.